# Select element "selected" not changing - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am sure this is (hopefully) going to turn out to be a really stupid question.

I'm making some basic alterations to a form for a client's website - evidently, the site loads a php script in an iFrame that writes 2/3 of the form.  The rest of the form is written in a JS file included on the original page after the php script has ended.

I had to, among other things, move a select into the part of the page that is written in JavaScript.

```
'   <td class="ttcell itemcell1 continent">' +
'   <select name="continent" id="continent" class="long-field" onchange="window.parent.calcTotals()">' +
'   <option value="NA">North America</option>' +
'   <option value="SA" selected>South America</option>' +
'   <option value="EU">Europe</option>' +
'   <option value="MO">Middle-Orient</option>' +
'   <option value="AA">Asia-Australia</option>' +
'   </select>' + 
'   </td>' +
```

I need to calculate a displayed value when the dropdown selection changes.  If I check the value in a JavaScript file included in the PHP document, which is called on form submit, I can check the value there.
However, I can't seem to find anywhere to bind the function.
If I have onclick as above in the original code, the event fires, but the selected value never changes.
If I check the value of the select in another function in the same JavaScript file, the value doesn't change.

The only place the change is reflected is when called from a function in the *other* PHP file...but trying to bind the event there doesn't seem to work.  I am starting to go slightly crazy...

**Edit**:
Solved by binding a click event in JS1 which called a function in JS2 returning the value.
In JS1 I was never able to read the true value of the select, and as such could never bind a change event.

Comment: There is no code here that would *cause* a change event to fire.  You have `onclick`, but that's *not* the same as `onchange`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is the only solution I could come up with within a reasonable time frame, so excuse the sketchiness.

The structure of the document was [I didn't write it]:
HTML (includes JS1) -> Loads HTML file onclick with an iFrame that loads a PHP script (which includes JS2).

I could bind an onclick event in JS1 - onchange would never work as the select attribute never changed.

So, I bound an onclick in JS1 which called the requisite function, which called a function in JS2 that returned $('#continent').val().

In JS1:

```
       ' <td class="ttcell itemcell1 continent">' +
   ' <select name="continent" id="continent" class="long-field" onclick="window.parent.calcTotals()">' +
   ' <option value="NA">North America</option>' +
   ' <option value="SA" selected>South America</option>' +
   ' <option value="EU">Europe</option>' +
   ' <option value="MO">Middle-Orient</option>' +
   ' <option value="AA">Asia-Australia</option>' +
   ' </select>' + 
   ' </td>' +...


    function calcTotals()
{       
   var $f = $("#cartFrame");
   out = $f[0].contentWindow.returnVal(); ...
```

In JS2:

```
function returnVal() {
return $('#continent').val();}
```

**Edit:**
Long since handed over this project, but I think about it from time to time.
What I suspect might have been happening was a jQuery conflict (iirc he had at least 2 different versions of jQuery being imported in different files).

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener for the `change` event in your JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('#continent').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    alert(e.target.value);
});
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/CeQAH/1/)

Comment: On a whim I decided to try adding this after the callback method for the iFrame loading.  No dice.

Answer (score 1):

First of all change the `onclick` event to `onchange`.

then, instead of using `:selected` to get the dropdown value, use `$("#continent").val()`